# value onSuccess is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Any]

Tags: scala, akka, future, actor

I want to make a request from a URL and am having a problem:

```
val f: Future[Any] = actor1 ? SyncRequest(url)
  f.onSuccess {
    case feed: xml.Elem => 
      val feedInfo = FeedInfo(
              ((feed \ "channel") \ "title").headOption.map(_.text).get,
              ((feed \ "channel") \ "description").headOption.map(_.text),
              ((feed \ "channel") \\ "item").map(item =>
                FeedItem((item \ "title").headOption.map(_.text).get,
                          (item \ "link").headOption.map(_.text))
              ).toList
            )

      complete(feedInfo)
```

This is the error:

```
[error] value onSuccess is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
[error]                 f.onSuccess {
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Maybe I have to use something like `OnComplete` and not `OnSuccess`?

Comment: The [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html) is your friend. Anyways, maybe you want `flatMap` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onSuccess` method is deprecated in Scala 2.12 and removed in scala 2.13

> @deprecated("use `foreach` or `onComplete` instead (keep in mind that
>   they take total rather than partial functions)", "2.12.0")

Your best friend is `onComplete` now

```
f.onComplete {
  case Success(value) => ???
  case Error(ex) => ???
}
```